# C# - Get the Model properties inside a List<Model> and SetValue with System.Reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reflection

I am doing a POC for a project that I am developing and at the moment I'm in kind of a hard spot.
So, I am receiving a param T which normally is a Model and then I have to check its properties to see which type the props are and then populate them.
To achieve this I am using `System.Reflection` which does the job wonderfully!
So far so good, It's working fine.

The problem is when the property in the model is a List

This is the example model that I have:

```
public List<TestModel2> TestList1 { get; set; }

public string test1 { get; set; }

public string test2 { get; set; }

public string test3 { get; set; }
```

So, the strings are totally fine, I can receive the Model, see their type and populate their value, the real problem arises when I get `TestList1` which I can't seem to get the `TestModel2` props and types.

This is a library that I am developing for a project, that's why the param type for the model is T by the way, it's because you can pass different models in which I will populate.

How can I access the Model inside the `List<TestModel2>` and check its properties and types with `System.Reflection`?

Can you guys give me a hint?

Comment: The fact that you need reflection rather than rely on OOP suggests something can be improved here.

Comment: Since you seem to have a working method for checking value properties on T you should consider making it recursive and if a property is a reference type it could simply call itself recursively and go through all its inner properties and so forth.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly happens when you receive a model which contains a `List` as a property, perhaps with a minimal reproducible code example?

Comment: @CoolBots I will edit the question and insert a little more code.